# Viber Chatbot - Creating an echo bot

Tags: node.js, chatbot, viber, viber-api, viber-bot

I was following the Viber Node.JS Bot Documentation and was creating an echo bot that would repeat the messages back to the user. But it does not work and the bot does not reply to my messages. Here is the code:

```
'use strict';

const ViberBot = require('viber-bot').Bot;
const BotEvents = require('viber-bot').Events;

const bot = new ViberBot({
    authToken: "api-key",
    name: "Override API",
    avatar: "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/customer-support-7/32/40_robot_bot_customer_help_support_automatic_reply-512.png" // It is recommended to be 720x720, and no more than 100kb.
});

// Perfect! Now here's the key part:
bot.on(BotEvents.MESSAGE_RECEIVED, (message, response) => {
    // Echo's back the message to the client. Your bot logic should sit here.
    response.send(message);
});


// Wasn't that easy? Let's create HTTPS server and set the webhook:
const https = require('https');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Viber will push messages sent to this URL. Web server should be internet-facing.
const webhookUrl = "https://webhook.site/09f0b45e-1ad8-466c-9441-e5edb3d783e3";

https.createServer(bot.middleware()).listen(port, () => bot.setWebhook(webhookUrl));
```

Comment: Do you use http or https server? I mean , where is your code running? On your computer or on server?

Comment: It's running on my computer

Comment: And what is your bot webhook url?

Comment: "https://webhook.site/09f0b45e-1ad8-466c-9441-e5edb3d783e3"

Answer (score 1):

**try this :**

```
const webhookUrl = "https://webhook.site/09f0b45e-1ad8-466c-9441-e5edb3d783e3";

app.use('/viber/webhook', bot.middleware());

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Application running on port: ${port}`);
    bot.setWebhook(`${webhookUrl}/viber/webhook`).catch(error => {
        console.log('Can not set webhook on following server. Is it running?');
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
});
```

**instead of:**

```
https.createServer(bot.middleware()).listen(port, () => bot.setWebhook(webhookUrl));
```

[Source](https://chatbotslife.com/build-viber-bot-with-nodejs-a21487e5b65)